# Retrieve records from a table based on multiple group by clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following tables:

**dbo.Customers**:

```
Id | Name | ...
```

**dbo.CaseTypes**:

```
Id | CustomerId | ...
```

**dbo.CaseTypeDocuments**:

```
Id | CaseTypeId | DocumentId | ...
```

**dbo.Documents**:

```
Id | Name | ...
```

**dbo.Questions**:

```
Id | DocumentId | ...
```

Documents can have 0 or more questions. A case type can have 0 or more documents.

I want to get list of customers and number of case types belonging to a customer with atleast two documents linked to it containing at least one question in each document.

So final result should look like:

```
Customer    |   CaseTypeCount
Cus1        |       10
Cus2        |       2
```

I have tried a few queries with inner joins which return results with wrong counts. Please suggest the right way of getting this result.

Answer (score 0):

Ajinkya,

I think you are looking something like this:

```
SELECT c.Name as 'Customer', COUNT(ct.Id) as 'CaseTypeCount' FROM Customers c 
       JOIN CaseTypes ct ON c.Id = ct.Id
       JOIN CaseTypeDocuments td ON ct.Id = td.Id
            WHERE td.DocumentId IN 
                  (SELECT d.Id FROM Documents d
                          JOIN Questions q ON d.Id = q.DocumentId)
GROUP BY c.Name HAVING COUNT(c.Name) >= 2
```

Maybe:

```
SELECT c.Name as 'Customer', COUNT(ct.Id) as 'CaseTypeCount' FROM Customers c 
       JOIN CaseTypes ct ON c.Id = ct.Id
       JOIN CaseTypeDocuments td ON ct.Id = td.Id
       JOIN Questions q ON d.Id = q.DocumentId)
GROUP BY c.Name HAVING COUNT(td.DocumentId) >= 2
```

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?  It looks like they want to test your understanding of the `HAVING` clause.
To find documents with at least one question, you can use an inner join:

```
select
  d.*
from
  documents d inner join
  questions q on
  d.id = q.documentID
```

but to find caseTypes with at least two documents, you need not only an `inner join`, but also the `group by` and `HAVING` clauses using the `HAVING` clause to limit by the aggregate function `count` of documentIDs, like

```
select
  c.id,
  count(d.id)
from 
  casetype c inner join
  documents d on
  c.documentid = d.id
group by
  c.id
having
  count(d.id) > 2
```